# Capturing specifics from audio streams

Tags: c#, wasapi, audio-capture

My aim is to capture two variables from an audio stream, these being frequencies and decibel level of each frequency (several frequency ranges is desired, so I'll end up grouping them, unless WASAPI can pull frequency ranges from the audio stream).

I've found that capturing audio streams is possible using WASAPI, but it appears to be based around C++. Is it possible to obtain the above mentioned variables using WASAPI and can I use WASAPI in C#?

Comment: Have you looked at NAudio? https://naudio.codeplex.com/

Comment: The documentation for it doesn't suggest its possible, but I'll download it and sift through anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Probably going to have to run your own FFT on the data to extract frequencies, but the raw data should be there. Sound level looks supported since one of the demos is a waveform/spectrum analyzer.

Comment: Well, thats basically all I'm trying to do is visualise audio, but on a peripheral. I wanted to get a bar sort of format rather than a wave, and decided it'd be best achieved by gathering the frequencies and grouping them or if possible gather them pre-grouped.

Comment: I think I may have found something... This looks like it may have the things I need https://wpfsvl.codeplex.com/

It shows visualised audio in the bar format, I'll do a  bit more reading into this one before I can say its resolved my question ah.

Comment: It turns out wpfsvl might not be what I was looking for. Theres no methods to obtain data from a stream external to the program. However looking more at NAudio, they have a very comprehensive XML file on it consisting of 21,700 lines (including the tags), and wpfsvl mentions using NAudio, so it's likely to have what I need. It will be while before I reply now as there's a fair amount of reading to do, so I thank you in advanced for sourcing this!